# retURL alternative in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning

Experiencing problems after switching to Lightning Experience - some vf actions after completion lead user to the home page.

We use saveURL and retURL a lot, which are not supported in Lghtnng.

Is there any alternative of saveURL and retURL in Lightning Experience?

Answer (score 2):

you might have to create a lightning component to do so and use [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm) in your controller in order to redirect the user to your home page after lead completion.

Controller.js Ex.

> opens an external website when the link is clicked

```
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {

    //Find the text value of the component with aura:id set to "address"
    var address = component.find("address").get("v.value");

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Unfortunately, locker service does not support saveURL and retURL as you mentioned, you can either use actions, however, I doubt you can achieve this with them, alternative = custom components (as far as i am concerned)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but initial idea was to  pass the hyperlink where to go after save (standard save).

Comment: unfortunately, locker service does not support saveURL and retURL as you mentioned, you can either use actions, however, i doubt you can achieve this with them, alternative = custom components (as far as i am concerned)